# Render MathJax in the 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, bug, 10k-tools, mathjax

In the [Space.SE 10k tools](https://space.stackexchange.com/tools), I noticed this:

[image]

There are two ugly dollar signs there - could we perhaps get that fixed?

Comment: A recent post on MathOverflow Meta, which seems related: [Some but not all LaTeX rendering correctly on tools page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5253#comment26966_5253).

Answer (score 5):

### Yes please! *(with freehand circles)*

I can confirm that the same problem exists also over at [Astronomy.SE 10K Tools](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last7days):

[image]

This is how it should look like (more or less):

[image]

Now, (spoiler alert!)

> I'm no unicorn,

but this should be easy enough to fix, right?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a simple oversight in the code that loads the tables over AJAX; it just needs to run:

```
typeof(MathJax) !== 'undefined' && MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
```

after each AJAX request completes to re-typeset any new math on the page.
I've included a piece of code that adds in this missing typeset call in a collection of small user script fixes that I'm calling the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Ps. Another similar issue (but with an unrelated cause) that I found while testing this is that, on the 10k flag review page, any math in posts hidden behind the "show posts you've already flagged" link is not typeset.  The problem here is that the `<div>` containing the hidden posts has the class `dno`, which both makes it invisible *and* causes MathJax to ignore it, and the code that un-hides it just uses jQuery `.show()` on it without actually removing the class name.  The Unofficial Patch linked above includes a fix for this issue too.